# parseJSON returning null in ajax success callback function in django template

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, django, django-templates

I have spent a lot of time on this problem.

I am using Django 1.6 and I am basically trying to send a request on button click through my django template using AJAX. On AJAX success, I am trying to alert that data for which I have requested.

This is my code in `views.py`

```
def requestFunction(request, ringslug):

LOGGER.info (" MYOBJ ")   
Myobj= Myobj.objects.get(slug=ringslug)    
LOGGER.info (Myobj)
LOGGER.info (type(Myobj))

if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
    LOGGER.info('is_ajax')
    context={'Myobj' : str(Myobj)}
    data = simplejson.dumps(context)
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="text/json")
```

So my `MyObj` is nothing but a query from the django DB and `data` is the JSONnified  data.

In my django template, this is how I am trying to retrieve it.

```
success: function(data) {


                                alert(data.MyObj) //returns obj name as given in DB
                                alert(typeof data.MyObj)   //string type
                                var MyParsedObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                                alert(typeof MyParsedObj)  //returns object type
                                alert(jQuery.parseJSON(data))  //returns null

                     },
```

So as you would have understood, `data` contains my DB information. My first question is how do I access the different DB fields from `data`? I have tried using `data.Myobj.MyDBField` but that did not work? My second question is why is the parsed data returning a null value in spite of returning the type as object.
Have been baffled with this for really long. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure casting your model instance to a string `str(MyObj)` is not serializing your instance as you expect

Comment: If I do not add that it tells me that my object is not json serializable